.NET MAUI Exception System.PlatformNotSupportedException
I am using .NET MAUI using Visual studio for Mac v17.6.10(build 428) with .net8 preview version and Microsoft.Identity.Client for maccatalyst. It throws exception as
**System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Darwin 23.1.0 Darwin Kernel Version 23.1.0**
 the details stack trace as follows
**Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.netcore.NetCorePlatformProxy.StartDefaultOsBrowserAsync(String url, Boolean isBrokerConfigured)\n   at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Platforms.Shared.Desktop.OsBrowser.DefaultOsBrowserWebUi.<>c__DisplayClass10_0**

The code as below
        var applicationOptions = new PublicClientApplicationOptions
        {
            ClientId = AuthenticationConfig.ApplicationID,
            RedirectUri = "http://localhost/",
        };
var PublicClient = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
                                        .CreateWithApplicationOptions(applicationOptions)
                                        .WithKerberosTicketClaim(UserEmailID, new MicrosoftIdentityClient.Kerberos.KerberosTicketContainer())
                                        .Build();
AuthenticationResultObj = await PublicClient.AcquireTokenInteractive((IEnumerable<string>)AuthenticationConfig.Scopes)
                                        .WithPrompt(MicrosoftIdentityClient.Prompt.Consent)
                                        .WithLoginHint(UserEmailID)
                                        .ExecuteAsync();

according to exception Microsoft.Identity.Client library I am using isn't compatible with the macOS version (Darwin kernel 23.1.0) or macOS Sonoma 14.1
Please suggest any changes required in code or project configuration.
Thanks in advance

Did this error only appear on  macOS version (Darwin kernel 23.1.0) or macOS Sonoma 14.1?

I specifically check the macOS Sonoma 14.1 environment, and since I only have the Sonoma 14.1 environment, I cannot confirm whether other macOS environments also show the error.

And didn't you test it on the other platforms?

yes I have tested it on Windows 11 machine and It works on that.

So the problem is special for the macos, you can report this on the github repo.
